# Modifying the wrapper element in smooth-dnd library

Tags: javascript, dom, npm, drag-and-drop

There is a library called [smooth-dnd](https://github.com/kutlugsahin/smooth-dnd/blob/master/src/container.ts) which is very useful for implementing drag n drop.
Suppose this were the code :

```
    <ul id="container">
        <li class="smooth-dnd-draggable-wrapper">Draggable 0</li>
        <li class="smooth-dnd-draggable-wrapper">Draggable 1</li>
    </ul>
```

And in the js file

```
    var containerElement = document.getElementById;
    var container = SmoothDnD.smoothDnD(containerElement, options);
```

After this the smooth dnd will be applied to my code and in the console it would look like this

```
<ul id="container" class="smooth-dnd-container vertical">
    <div class="smooth-dnd-draggable-wrapper">
                <li>Draggable 0</li>
    </div>
    <div class="smooth-dnd-draggable-wrapper">
                <li>Draggable 1</li>
    </div>
</ul>
```

So, you see there is a div wrapper added to the li element before dropping the draggable item. Now, I want to modify this wrapper. One thing which I thought of was to do it manually before dropping the draggable like taking the parent element of li and modify it but it is like a hack thing. Any other idea as the library doesn't provide anything